# Excel - capture multiple data columns into 1 cell as text with heading & value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have spreadsheet with 50+ rows of project installation data, that is separated across 5 different columns. I need to provide a summary of each project ID, with the results of each install data columns summarized into 1 cell as text.

Is there a way to collate the value for each cell row in Columns B-F, into 1 summary text cell where the result of each row matches the heading of that Column?

In my screenshot below, cell G2 is a sample of the desired format of the final summary result, however I want the data in cells B2:F2 to appear next to each relevant heading.

I have tried a few things but cat work out how to get the format of the final summary result

Can anyone help with this problem?

[image]

Comment: Try to use TEXTJOIN() worksheet function - it is available in your application version.

Comment: I have never used that before. How does it work?

Comment: [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Comment: Use `":" & CHAR(10) & "- "` as delimiter, and delete 2 chars from each side of TEXTLOIN() result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In G2, put :

```
="- "&$B$1&" : "&B2&CHAR(10)&"- "&$C$1&" : "&C2&CHAR(10)&"- "&$D$1&" : "&D2&CHAR(10)&"- "&$E$1&" : "&E2&CHAR(10)&"- "&$F$1&" : "&F2
```

and drag downwards. Make sure "wrap text" option in the cell format is selected too.

idea : $ is used to lock the formula column/row. char(10) is for the 'newline' character. & symbol functions similar to concatenate or textjoin excel function, just imho more straightforward (that's why I use it).

kindly share if it works/not. (:

Comment: Hi there p._phidot,yes that worked well thanks so much. I have never used the CHAR(10) formula, so this is very handy to know

Comment: Credit to the initial comment, I just learnt it from @Akina. Btw, if you accept this answer please click the tick to remove this question from the 'unanswered' list. ( :

Comment: Yes thanks to both Akina and p._phidot for helping me solve this excel problem!